# wxWidgets equivalent of PyTk's update_idletasks?

Tags: tkinter, wxwidgets

I'm porting a video player from PyTk to wxWidgets.

I have a separate worker thread that pushes events to the main app via `wx.PostEvent` every 30ms (based on these instructions: http://wiki.wxpython.org/Non-Blocking%20Gui).  The main app is supposed to read a new frame from the video file and display it.  The event gets received and handled properly (confirmed via debug statements), but the actual image on the screen doesn't update.  The GUI only updates after the worker thread terminates -- so I only get to see the last frame.

My frame reading and display code works correctly -- I've tested it using a slider.  I can't work out the reason why the GUI isn't updating.

In PyTk, there is a method called update_idletasks that forces a widget repaint.  I have a feeling that I need to do something similar in wxWidgets -- is this the case?  If yes, then what is the wxWidgets alternative to update_idletasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: this is more of a windows thing than wxWidgets.  I guess you might need to tell the window manager that the window containing the video frame needs to be repainted.  A call to Refresh() or Invalidate() on that window might be worth trying.

Comment: You are correct.  Within the event handling code, I had to call self.Refresh() followed by self.Update() for things to work.  Thank you.